# JQuery autocomplete : Preventing text replace when focus

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have the following code for autocomplete :

```
$(function() {
    var availableTags = [
                " x",
                "y",
                "z",
                "l",
                "m",
                "n",
                "o",
              ];

    $( ".tags" ).autocomplete({
          source: availableTags,position: { my : "left+2 bottom-50" , of:".tags"}
    });
 });
```

It works fine but when I select the suggested text using up/down keys, the selected text is immediately replaced in the text field. Instead, I want it to be replaced only when ENTER is pressed on the selection. Any way to achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent update of input element when an item is selected in a jQueryUI autocomplete list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16701589/how-to-prevent-update-of-input-element-when-an-item-is-selected-in-a-jqueryui-au)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When suggestion elements are viewed (using arrows key too) is triggered the [`focus`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-focus) event, so you can simply prevent the default action using [`preventDefault`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) method.

Quick reference on focus:

> Triggered when focus is moved to an item (not selecting). The default
>   action is to replace the text field's value with the value of the
>   focused item, though only if the event was triggered by a keyboard
>   interaction. Canceling this event prevents the value from being
>   updated, but does not prevent the menu item from being focused.

Code:

```
$(function () {
    var availableTags = [
        "ActionScript",
        "AppleScript",
        "Asp",
        "BASIC",
        "C",
        "C++",
        "Clojure",
        "COBOL",
        "ColdFusion",
        "Erlang",
        "Fortran",
        "Groovy",
        "Haskell",
        "Java",
        "JavaScript",
        "Lisp",
        "Perl",
        "PHP",
        "Python",
        "Ruby",
        "Scala",
        "Scheme"];



    $("#tags").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags,
        position: {
            my: "left bottom",
            at: "left top",
        },
        focus: function (event, ui) {
           event.preventDefault();
        }

    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/TgmPQ/

Answer (score 3):

```
focus: function (event, ui) {
       event.preventDefault();
 }
```

Try this. This will not change your value on focus! Please note `your-input-field-id` is the id of your input field.

Comment: You have to preventDefault to let this work, set the value is not sufficient. See my answer